# SQL Query that gets latest version of table and sorted by other table's name variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have two tables in my sql, one is deployments and other one is applications. I'm trying to get latest version (it's calculated according to update_at variable) and i want to order them by application name. app_id in deployment table is equal to id in application table. One line in application table can more than one deployment line in deployment table which means they got one to many relationship.

```
Deployment table
id
app_id
version
created_at
updated_at

Application table:
id
name
created_at
updated_at
image
```

i wrote sth like this, but it's not working. can someone help me?

```
SELECT d.*
FROM deployments d
INNER JOIN
(SELECT de.app_id, MAX(de.updated_at) AS MaxDateTime FROM deployments de, applications a GROUP BY de.app_id ORDER BY a.name) grouped_deployments
ON d.app_id = grouped_deployments.app_id
AND d.updated_at = grouped_deployments.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: Comma-separated joins are a relict of the 1980s. That is before MySQL was invented. Why do you use that? And why are you cross joining deployments and applications? That must be a mistake, right?

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: i'm sorry, i remember that from my class so i tried to use it. Version isMySQL 5.7 and i cannot change it because it's not personal project.

Comment: Okay, so that may have been a bad class :-) Use explicit joins instead (`INNER JOIN ON | LEFT JOIN ON | CROSS JOIN`). In your case you don't need a join at all (but you can join, if you want). Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the latest version per application, a correlated subquery is enough:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select d.version 
        from deployments d 
        where d.app_id = a.id 
        order by d.updated_at desc 
        limit 1
    ) last_version
from applications a
order by a.app_name
```

This should be an efficient solution, provided that you have an index on `deployments(app_id, updated_at, version)`.

If you want more columns from the `deployments` table, then an option is a `join` and filtering with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.app_name, d.version, d.updated_at, d.created_at
from applications a
inner join deployments d on d.app_id = a.id
where d.updated_at = (
    select max(d1.updated_at) from deployments d1 where d1.app_id = a.app_id
)
order by a.app_name
```

Comment: deployment table does not have a variable named app_name/name. It belongs to applications table.

Comment: @meursault: yes, the query takes this into account (you might need to refresh the page to get the latest version of the answer).

Comment: i'm looking at the active answer and it has sth like this in the end: order by d.app_name which does not work on me :(

Comment: @meursault: my bad, it had to be `order by a.app_name`. Fixed.

Comment: and one more thing i dont want to get results from application table because for ex. one line in application table has more than one line in deployment table (many to one) i want to choose latest version from deployment table. Which i want to say all updates of apps are stored in deployment but only name is remains in application

Comment: @meursault: yes. This query gives you the results that you want. Try it against your actual data.

Comment: yes, but i  also want to get updated_at and created_at from deployments, is it possible? Result shows me first version's (updated_at and created_at) variables because of a.*

Comment: @meursault: that was not part of your original question, that just stated you want the latest version... See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you kind sir/lady :) it's working! have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last deployment per app, you can use `IN` with an aggregation subquery:

```
select * 
from applications a
join deployments d on d.app_id = a.id
where (d.app_id, d.updated_at) in
(
  select app_id, max(updated_at)
  from deployments
  group by app_id
)
order by a.name;
```

Comment: yes i want latest version but i also want to sort them by name which is variable in applications table. Applications table and Deployment table is connected with id and app_id respectively.

Comment: Then just join with the application table and add the desired `ORDER BY`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i'm getting an error which says Error Code: 1052. Column 'updated_at' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous :(

Comment: This is because both tables have a column called `updated_at`. I simply forgot to qualify the columns with the table names when I added the join. You should learn to understand error messages. Then you would have been able to spot and fix this yourself. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT de.*
FROM application a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT d.app_id, MAX(d.updated_at) AS MaxDateTime FROM deployments d GROUP BY d.app_id) de
on de.app_id = a.id
order by a.name;
```

**Edit For Multiple Columns:**
Older versions of mysql allowed non aggregate columns in select list. In newer versions (5.7+), you can remove sql mode "only_full_group_by" to get the same effect. Now, you can add all columns in the derived table.

If you want portable query, you need to join back to get the result:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM application a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT d.app_id, MAX(d.updated_at) AS MaxDateTime FROM deployments d GROUP BY d.app_id) de
on de.app_id = a.id
INNER JOIN deployments d
ON d.updated_at = de.update_at
order by a.name;
```

Comment: it's working but is it possible to get version, created_at and id columns from deployments too? it only prints app_id and updated_at columns. i tried to write it in inner select but it gave error